# Rails: Prevent will_paginate from calling #count of ActiveRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, will-paginate

When I pass `will_paginate` an ActiveRelation, it always calls its #count method and hits the database to find out the total number of items. But this operation takes time and I have the total number already cached and ready. Can I pass this pre-calculated count to `will_paginate` and stop it from hitting the database?

I tried the `:count` option, but it is passed to ActiveRecord as an option:

```
active_relation.paginate(page: 2, per_page: 100, count: total_count)
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Passing the cached count with `:total_entries` solves the problem:

```rb
active_relation.paginate(page: 2, per_page: 100, total_entries: total_count)
```